# Deal with 'NoneType' object is not iterable' error in a list of comprehension

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape quantity from a site using this code:

```
qty = [qty.text.strip() for qty in soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"item-quantity"})]
```

but the value is not always present so I'm getting this error:

```
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

is there a way to insert an if and else statement in a list of comprehension? So that when the quantity is not present in the list the value "1" is saved.
I've tried

```
qty = [qty.text.strip() for qty in soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"item-quantity"})if x is not None else x="1"]
```

But I'm getting an error of invalid syntax

Comment: Proper syntax should be `qty = [qty.text.strip() for qty in soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"item-quantity"}) if qty is not None else "1"]`.

Comment: Does this work at all? According to the docs, `soup.find` never returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a for loop here, but here's one way to do this

```
qty = [qty.text.strip() for qty in soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"item-quantity"}) or []]
```

Since None is Falsy, it evaluates the expression after `or`

```
print(None or []) # []
print([1,2,3] or []) # [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`List comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) have the ability to use `ternary expressions` like this:

```py
qty = [qty.text.strip() if qty else "1" for qty in soup.find("span", attrs={"class":"item-quantity"})]
```

It is also possible to use a normal loop and add `try/except` instead of an `if/else`.